# Error IGZ0035S when attempting to open an output dataset in COBOL

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I have created two datasets `PRT-DONE` and `PRT-LINE` in output. But when I am submitting job it is showing unsuccessful opening of `PRT-DONE` output; `PRT-LINE` is working fine.

I think it cannot open the datasets `PRT-DONE`. Looks like opening error of the output PRTDONE. When I was removing that open statement there was only condition code error.

**Error:**
IGZ0035S There was an unsuccessful OPEN or CLOSE of file PRTDONE in program ADDONE at relative location X'318'.

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID.    ADDONE.
       AUTHOR.        STUDENT.
      *
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
      *
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
           SELECT PRT-LINE ASSIGN TO PRTLINE.
           SELECT PRT-DONE ASSIGN TO PRTDONE.

       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       FD  PRT-LINE RECORD CONTAINS 80 CHARACTERS RECORDING MODE F.
       01  PRT-REC        PIC X(80) VALUE SPACES.

       FD  PRT-DONE RECORD CONTAINS 80 CHARACTERS RECORDING MODE F.
       01  PRT-REC-DONE.
           05  PRT-DATE     PIC X(8)  VALUE SPACES.
           05  FILLER       PIC X(1)  VALUE SPACES.
           05  PRT-TIME     PIC X(4)  VALUE SPACES.
           05  FILLER       PIC X(2)  VALUE SPACES.
           05  PRT-COMMENT  PIC X(27) VALUE SPACES.
           05  FILLER       PIC X(2)  VALUE SPACES.
           05  PRT-MY-NAME  PIC X(36) VALUE SPACES.

       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

       01  PGM-VARIABLES.
           05  PGM-COUNT    PIC 9(05).

       01  YYYYMMDD         PIC 9(8).

       01  INTEGER-FORM     PIC S9(9).

       01  REFMOD-TIME-ITEM PIC X(8).

      ****************************************************************
      *                  PROCEDURE DIVISION                          *
      ****************************************************************
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
      *
       A000-START.
           OPEN OUTPUT PRT-LINE.
           PERFORM A000-COUNT 10 TIMES.
           PERFORM A000-DONE.
           CLOSE   PRT-LINE.
           STOP RUN.
      *
       A000-COUNT.
           ADD 1 TO PGM-COUNT.
      *    DISPLAY PGM-COUNT.
           WRITE PRT-REC FROM  PGM-COUNT.
      *
       A000-DONE.
           OPEN OUTPUT PRT-DONE.
           MOVE SPACES TO PRT-REC-DONE.
           ACCEPT REFMOD-TIME-ITEM FROM TIME.
           MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE(1:8) TO YYYYMMDD.
           MOVE YYYYMMDD         TO PRT-DATE.
           MOVE REFMOD-TIME-ITEM (1:4) TO PRT-TIME.
           MOVE "My first z/OS COBOL program" TO PRT-COMMENT.
           WRITE PRT-REC-DONE.
           CLOSE PRT-DONE.
```

JCL:

```
//ADD1JCL  JOB 1,NOTIFY=&SYSUID
//*****************/
//COBRUN  EXEC IGYWCL
//COBOL.SYSIN  DD DSN=&SYSUID..SOURCE(ADD1CBL),DISP=SHR
//LKED.SYSLMOD DD DSN=&SYSUID..LOAD(ADD1CBL),DISP=SHR
//*****************/
// IF RC = 0 THEN
//*****************/
//RUN     EXEC PGM=ADD1CBL
//STEPLIB   DD DSN=&SYSUID..LOAD,DISP=SHR
//PRTDONE   DD  DSN=Z12441.OUTPUT(PRTDONE),DISP=SHR,OUTLIM=15000
//PRTLINE   DD  DSN=Z12441.OUTPUT(PRTLINE),DISP=SHR,OUTLIM=15000
//SYSOUT    DD SYSOUT=*,OUTLIM=15000
//CEEDUMP   DD DUMMY
//SYSUDUMP  DD DUMMY
//*****************/
// ELSE
// ENDIF
```

Comment: //ADD1JCL  JOB 1,NOTIFY=&SYSUID
//*****************/
//COBRUN  EXEC IGYWCL
//COBOL.SYSIN  DD DSN=&SYSUID..SOURCE(ADD1CBL),DISP=SHR
//LKED.SYSLMOD DD DSN=&SYSUID..LOAD(ADD1CBL),DISP=SHR
//*****************/
// IF RC = 0 THEN
//*****************/
//RUN     EXEC PGM=ADD1CBL
//STEPLIB   DD DSN=&SYSUID..LOAD,DISP=SHR
//PRTDONE   DD  DSN=Z12441.OUTPUT(PRTDONE),DISP=SHR,OUTLIM=15000
//PRTLINE   DD  DSN=Z12441.OUTPUT(PRTLINE),DISP=SHR,OUTLIM=15000
//SYSOUT    DD SYSOUT=*,OUTLIM=15000
//CEEDUMP   DD DUMMY
//SYSUDUMP  DD DUMMY
//*****************/
// ELSE
// ENDIF

Comment: IGZ0035S There was an unsuccessful OPEN or CLOSE of file PRTDONE in program ADDONE at relative location X'318'.   This was the error

Comment: Note that the `OUTLIM=` DD statement parameter is only meaningful for `SYSOUT` statements, i.e. `//ANYDD DD SYSOUT=*,OUTLIM=123`. The system might not accept that parameter on a non-SYSOUT DD statement. This would be a JCL error, though, not an "abend-like" error.

Comment: I have edited the code and added jcl code please check.

Answer (score 4):

I assume your output data set `Z12441.OUTPUT` is of type PDS not PDS/E. You're trying to write to two members in the same PDS in parallel, which is not supported. In your job's output, you probably see a message `IEC143I 213-30,...`. Where `213` is the ABEND code which points to a problem with the OPEN service, and `30` is the return code. The explanation of messsage `IEC143I` can be found here [Message description](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=messages-iec143i). The explanation for reason code 30 sais:

*An attempt was made to open a partitioned data set (PDS) for OUTPUT,DISP=SHR. The PDS is already open in this condition, and a DCB is already open for output to the data set. The data set might be on the same system or on another system that is sharing the volume. Access was not serialized before the attempt to open the data set.*

You need to allocate two distinct output data sets, one for `PRTDONE`, and one for `PRTLINE`. Two members of the same PDS are *not* two distinct data sets.

**Note** that PDS/E data sets allow multiple concurrent opens for output to different members, with some restrictions. I would advise to *not* get used to opening for *output* multiple members of the same PDS or PDS/E at the same time. Rather use PS data sets than PDS members for output. One reason being the restartability of jobs. With PS data sets, you can simply delete and reallocate the data set within a job, and then rerun the job. It is more complex to handle restartability with PDS members.

Comment: But how can I create PS data sets in ibm mainframe because there are options of PDS and SDS only to be created.

Comment: Would you please start another, separate question for this so that I (we) can write answer(s) that relate to the question. I'd rather not add it here.

Comment: This was solved when I did this. Thank you.